# locked out from Wordpress with php header location

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I have a wordpress site and with a code snippet created a php header location redirect. Now I have locked myself out and can no longer get to the wordpress page. Neither in the frontend nor in the backend. Can I restore the access?

I tried renaming the plugin's folder, hoping that would disable the plugin. No chance.

In the wp_config I also already tried to use define('CODE_SNIPPETS_SAFE_MODE', true );. But even here the header location is still executed and I am always taken to another page.

***update***

I have read that code-snippet stores its entries in the database. So I have to wait until I have the access and then I can solve the problem. Thanks anyway for your support,.

Comment: "locked out" how eactly? What exactly is the specific issue / error you are experiencing? And why can't you edit the source code to remove this snippet again, if you think that caused the problem? Editing the source does not rely on having access to the application's front-end.

Comment: First of all, make sure you are not getting fooled by your bowser cache - if the redirect was made with status code 301, browsers tend to _cache_ that real hard. So try in a private window/tab, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: If not - the code is probably stored in the database somewhere, if you hacked this in via some "execute PHP code snippets" plugin; so I would go look for it there, and try and delete the corresponding record.

Comment: I have already tried clearing the browser cache. A private window does not help either.

I used the following command in the code-snippet:
header("Location: https://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();

I don't have access to phpmyadmin at the moment and therefore I can't delete the entry in the database, if it exists there. :-(